# Using ES6/7 in AppMaker Scripts

Tags: google-app-maker

When using arrow functions:

```
[cbCenter, edtTitle].forEach(widget => widget.validate());
```

The following warning is displayed

[image]

The code runs correctly, so I just need to know how to enable the esnext option to get rid of the warning?

Comment: After further research, it appears this is a jshint option, but settings /* jshint esnext */ or /*jshint esversion:6 */ client side results in an invalid option error. So this may be something to be fixed sever side with the linter configuration

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax is awkward, you should add the following to the top of your script:

/* jshint esnext:true */

Note that as the other answer says, this will *not* work for server-side scripts, because Apps Script doesn't support es6. But it will work fine for client-side scripts.